# Where is the memory leak here relating to Texture2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a memory leak, and I have it isolated down to this script, and I think it is a problem with the game making a new texture every frame, but I don't actually know how to fix it.

I have read online that creating a texture every frame is bad as it is an engine-managed resource, so it is not automatically garbage collected, and that I need to release it, but I don't know where to release it. Should I make a late update where I release it?

```
public float height = 10f;
public float width = 2f;
public float defaultSpread = 10f;
public Color color = Color.grey;
public bool resizeable = false;
public float resizedSpread = 20f;
public float resizeSpeed = 3f;
[SerializeField]
float velocityMin = 210;

float spread;
bool resizing = false;

CharacterController player;

void Awake()
{
    //set spread
    spread = defaultSpread;
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (player.velocity.sqrMagnitude > velocityMin) { resizing = true; } else { resizing = false; }

    if (resizeable)
    {
        if (resizing)
        {
            //increase spread 
            spread = Mathf.Lerp(spread, resizedSpread, resizeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            //decrease spread
            spread = Mathf.Lerp(spread, defaultSpread, resizeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        //clamp spread
        spread = Mathf.Clamp(spread, defaultSpread, resizedSpread);
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture.SetPixel(0, 0, color);
    texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
    texture.Apply();

    //up rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - width / 2, (Screen.height / 2 - height / 2) + spread / 2, width, height), texture);

    //down rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - width / 2, (Screen.height / 2 - height / 2) - spread / 2, width, height), texture);

    //left rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect((Screen.width / 2 - height / 2) + spread / 2, Screen.height / 2 - width / 2, height, width), texture);

    //right rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect((Screen.width / 2 - height / 2) - spread / 2, Screen.height / 2 - width / 2, height, width), texture);
}

public void SetRisizing(bool state)
{
    resizing = state;
}
```

Comment: You create a new Texture each round and it seems Unity does not collect unused Textures. Not sure if by design or requirement but for a Texture to be collected, it needs to be destroyed explicitly. But in your case, the persistent solution is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! As @Athanasios Kataras suggested, making the variable persist solved the problem. I had actually tried to make it persist before, but it did not work. I only now remembered that I did not actually save the file.

Here is the reworked code:

```
public float height = 10f;
public float width = 2f;
public float defaultSpread = 10f;
public Color color = Color.grey;
public bool resizeable = false;
public float resizedSpread = 20f;
public float resizeSpeed = 3f;
[SerializeField]
float velocityMin = 210;

float spread = 0;
bool resizing = false;

CharacterController player;

Texture2D texture;

void Awake()
{
    //set spread
    spread = defaultSpread;
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<CharacterController>();

    texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    texture.SetPixel(0, 0, color);
    texture.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Repeat;
    texture.Apply();
}

void Update()
{
    if (player.velocity.sqrMagnitude > velocityMin) { resizing = true; } else { resizing = false; }

    if (resizeable)
    {
        if (resizing)
        {
            //increase spread 
            spread = Mathf.Lerp(spread, resizedSpread, resizeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            //decrease spread
            spread = Mathf.Lerp(spread, defaultSpread, resizeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        //clamp spread
        spread = Mathf.Clamp(spread, defaultSpread, resizedSpread);
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    //up rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - width / 2, (Screen.height / 2 - height / 2) + spread / 2, width, height), texture);

    //down rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - width / 2, (Screen.height / 2 - height / 2) - spread / 2, width, height), texture);

    //left rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect((Screen.width / 2 - height / 2) + spread / 2, Screen.height / 2 - width / 2, height, width), texture);

    //right rect
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect((Screen.width / 2 - height / 2) - spread / 2, Screen.height / 2 - width / 2, height, width), texture);
}
```

It is still running in OnGUI because I am using GUI functions, and also because I get 400 fps when this game is running, I really don't need to spend the time to edge out a tiny bit of performance.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you running this code in onGui function?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnGUI.html

> Your OnGUI implementation might be called several times per frame (one call per event).

From the IMGUI documentation:https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GUIScriptingGuide.html

> The IMGUI system is not generally intended to be used for normal in-game user interfaces that players might use and interact with. For that you should use Unity’s main GameObject-based UI system, which offers a GameObject-based approach for editing and positioning UI elements, and has far better tools to work with the visual design and layout of the UI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but in this case, I was asking how I can solve my memory leak here?

Comment: Simplest way, draw it only once. Persist the information in some way (easiest way would be a private static variable) and add the texture the first time only.

Comment: Wait, GUI functions can only be called in OnGUI, that is why I did it there. Would you suggest an alternative method?

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/43414/destroying-drawn-gui-texture.html